# How to repurpose my directive here to work in 2 different scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

http://plnkr.co/edit/39FGMocKB5GtQWnI1TFw?p=preview

I have **sidebar** which contains a list of tags, when you click on a tag I use the `TagDetailsFactory` to send a tag into the scope of the **view** controller.

Everything works great except for when you hover over a tag in the TagDetailsFactory scope.

The `tagDetails` template does not show up, however if you hover over the same tag in the sidebar scope, the `tagDetails` shows up in both. This is wrong.

Hovering over a tag in the sidebar should only show the tag details for that tag and the same for the tags inside the view scope.

---

Hovering over a tag in the view scope, doesn't display it's details 
[image]

---

Hovering over a tag inside of the sidebar scope, should only show details for it's tag, and not the tag in the view scope, like it does here:
[image]

---

**Steps:**
- The first tags Array is in the cnt controller
- When you click on a tag, it gets stored in the TagDetailsFactory service
- I then broadcast an event to the view controller to then call the getTagDetails function in TagDetailsFactory to retrieve the saved tags and store them into the viewTags array in the view controller.

---

```
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', [])

.directive('tagDetails', function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      // console.debug($scope, attrs);
    },
    scope:{
        tag:'='
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="tag.showDetails">{{tag.details}}</div>'
  };
})

.factory('TagDetailsFactory', function() {

        var savedTags = [];

        var saveTagDetails = function(tag) {
          savedTags.push(tag);
        }

        var getTagDetails = function() {
          return savedTags;
        }

        return {
            saveTagDetails : saveTagDetails,
            getTagDetails  : getTagDetails
        };
})

.controller('sidebar', function($scope,
                             $rootScope,
                             TagDetailsFactory) {
  $scope.tags = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.tags.push(
      { name: 'Foo Bar ' + i, details: 'Details' + i }
    );
  }

  $scope.showTagDetails = function(t) {
    t.showDetails = true;
  }

  $scope.leaveTag = function(t) {
    t.showDetails = false;
  }

  $scope.sendTag = function(t) {
    TagDetailsFactory.saveTagDetails(t);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('updateView'); 
  }

})

.controller('view', function($scope,
                              $rootScope,
                              TagDetailsFactory) {

  $scope.viewTags = [];

  $scope.$on('updateView', function() {
    $scope.viewTags = TagDetailsFactory.getTagDetails();
  });

  $scope.showTagDetails = function(v) {
    v.showDetails = true;
  }

  $scope.leaveTag = function(v) {
    v.showDetails = false;
  }

});
```

Do I have to create a 2nd directive here? To be the template for the tag details in the view scope? Or can my current `tagDetails` directive be repurposed somehow in an Angular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1uj8voPjZhWFNtXPspvG?p=preview) with a working copy, and I'll explain the changes I made.

You have two issues with the code here.  The first is a simple typo, which is causing your header to not reference the correct function for mouseover.  Your functions are calling `showTagDetailsView(v)`and `leaveTagView(v)`, but they are named `showTagDetails` and `leaveTag` on the controller.

The second issue is with the way that the items are added to the `savedTags[]`.  In JavaScript, objects are passed by reference.  when you call `savedTags.push(tag);`, you are pushing a reference to the same object into the new array.  Any changes made to the object in one array will be reflected in the other array.

Instead, what you want is a separate copy of the object in the `savedTags[]`.  This can be accomplished by using [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy#!/).  Note that I also reset `tag.showDetails = false;` before making the copy, else the new copy will have it set to true, and the details will be showing the instant the copy appears, even though you are hovering over the other element when you click it.

```
var saveTagDetails = function(tag) {
    tag.showDetails = false;
    savedTags.push(angular.copy(tag));
}
```

Just a side note, you might also have an issue with CSS here, as hovering seems to change the position of the lists, and in some cases the hover actually causes the tag to move itself out of the hover, causing a bounce effect.

Comment: Brilliant man! Thanks for the tips too and additional details :)